# ML .net reading in tab seperated data set

Tags: .net, ml.net

Its my first time using ML.net 0.8 and I'm having troubling loading in my dataset.

```
var mlContext = new MLContext();

        String dataPath = "ML Data 3.txt";
        var trainingDataView = mlContext.Data.ReadFromTextFile(
            columns: new TextLoader.Column[]
            {
                new TextLoader.Column("Product", DataKind.Text,0),
                new TextLoader.Column("Streat", DataKind.R4, 1),
                new TextLoader.Column("Overspray", DataKind.R4,2),
                new TextLoader.Column("MLS",DataKind.R4,3),
                new TextLoader.Column("Moisture",DataKind.R4,4)
            }, path: dataPath );


        var data = trainingDataView.Preview();

        var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Product", "Streat", "Overspray", "MLS")
            .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumn: "Moisture", featureColumn: "Features"))
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedMoisture"));


        var model = pipeline.Fit(trainingDataView);
```

The data preview looks good, however when it tries to fit to perform the Fit operation I receive the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Column 'Streat' has values of R4which is not the same as earlier observed type of Text.'

I have checked the data and there are no Text elements within the data file, other than the Product column.

[image: SampleDataSet]

Any advice greatly received.

Answer (score 2):

`MulticlassClassification` algorithm won't work with text features, only numbers. If `Product` is some kind of identifier, you'd better to exclude it from `Concatenate` call since it's not a feature:

```
mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Streat", "Overspray", "MLS")
```

If it's some kind of category and should be used as a feature, you can convert it to a number using one of transformations, like `OneHotEncoding`:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Categorical.OneHotEncoding("Product")
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Product", "Streat", "Overspray", "MLS"))
        .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.StochasticDualCoordinateAscent(labelColumn: "Moisture", featureColumn: "Features"))
        .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedMoisture"));
```

Comment: Thanks Random, I realised my mistake shortly after posting. Changed my model to use a regression algorithm and the above error messages were resolved.